# jQuery Lightbox. Can't find method

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I'm surely having a simple issue here but just can't get hold of it.
I would like to trigger lightbox with jquery as described [here](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) but it just won't do.
.lightBox() Method can not be found and I just don't understand why.

Code is

```
<!-- jquery lighbox addon -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>

<!-- Lightbox active for all a elements with longdesc="lb" -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $('a[longdesc="lb"]').lightBox();
     });
</script>
```

And error message is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lightBox'
```

Thanks a million for your help in advance!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your relative link to the script is correct?  Have you tried viewing the page source in browser and clicking on the script link to ensure that the script is at that location?

Comment: Probably '`files/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js`' path is wrong, check that.

Comment: Calling up jquery.lightbox-0.5.js with (Chromes) console link worked fine. I also deliberately changed the file name to check, if it would throw an error and it did. So I presume the link is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download lightbox, extract it out, and copy the jquery.lightbox-0.5.js file into your /files/ folder. Verify that your path to the file is correct relative to the HTML file you are running this from, or you can make it absolute by putting a leading slash in front of files, like /files/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js.

Comment: Calling up jquery.lightbox-0.5.js with (Chromes) console link worked fine. I also deliberately changed the file name to check, if it would throw an error and it did. So I presume the link is ok.